# Clear and redraw view in eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, view, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I've created a custom view in my Eclipse application using [this](https://eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html) tutorial, which is responsible for visualizing a graph (defined by different points, stored in an array).

This view also contains a drop-down-menu, where the user can choose between diferent graph names.

This is my code:

```
private List<Action> actionList = new ArrayList<Action>();

HashMap<String, int[]> graphCoordinates = new HashMap<String, int[]>();

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    declareMaps();
    createActions();
    createMenu();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            if (graphCoordinates.isEmpty()) {
                declareGraphCoordinates(e.width, e.height);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void createActions() {
    for (String column : graphNames) {
        Action action = new Action(column) {
            public void run() {
                int[] polylinePoints = graphCoordinates.get(getId());
                // TODO: Draw!
            }
        };
        action.setId(column);
        actionList.add(action);
    }
}

private void createMenu() {
    IMenuManager mgr = getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager();
    for (int i = 0; i < graphNames.size(); i++) {
        mgr.add(actionList.get(i));
    }
}
```

The `declareMaps()` method is quite extensive. It declares maps, which hold the coordinates for the graphs, that have to be drawn. Mainly it adds the graphs to the `HashMap` `graphCoordinates`, where the key is the graph name and the value is an `int[]` with the polyline points. But this is not the problem.

In `createActions()` I am defining `Action` objects for each graph and store them in a `ArrayList`.
In `createMenu()` I add the `Actions` to the menu.

This implementation allows the user to choose the graph name in the menu of my view and after he clicks one of them, the `run()` method of the corresponding `Action` is called. Inside that `run()` method I want to clear the view and draw the new graph, depending on the user decision with:

```
e.gc.drawPolyline(graphCoordinates.get(userDecision));
```

Reading the user decision is also not the problem but how do I reset the view (deleting the old graph, if necessary) and draw the new graph? The drawing happens inside the `createPartControl()` method. Do I have to call it again or what would be the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `redraw()` on the canvas control to tell it that you want it redrawn. This will cause the paint listener to be called again. In the `PaintListener` draw whatever has been chosen.

Comment: Thank you very much! Once again you helped me a lot!